# Combining multiple rx sources

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

Lets imagine following situation, we have a function that return Observable source of objects from server side:

```
private fun getStatistics(): Observable<TestStatistics> {
        return Observable
                .fromIterable(listOf(
                        TestStatistics(1.1, 1.2, 4),
                        TestStatistics(2.1, 2.2, 1),
                        TestStatistics(3.1, 3.2, 99)
                ))
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

TestStatistics entity:

```
data class TestStatistics(val doubleCashBack: Double, val doubleAmount: Double, val currencyId: Int)
```

As you can see in server response we have currencyId which point us to Currency entity:

```
data class TestCurrency(val currencyId: Int, val currencySign: String)
```

And we have another function that return Single source of Currency entity by id from database:

```
private fun getCurrencyById(id: Int): Single<TestCurrency> {
        return when (id) {
            1 -> Single.just(TestCurrency(1, "!"))
            2 -> Single.just(TestCurrency(2, "@"))
            3 -> Single.just(TestCurrency(3, "#"))
            else -> Single.error(Exception("Currency not found"))
        }
                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

The main idea is to take every emitted Statistic entity, take it's properties a combine them and than emit combined entity with properties and Currency as object, so here comes problem, in this case we have to take currencyId take first successfully received Currency object from database and than emit result entity, so result class will look like:

```
data class TestDashboardStatistics(val count: Int, val cashBack: Double, val amount: Double, val testCurrency: TestCurrency)
```

But I have some problems with this combination of observable sources, server request runs in one thread, database in another and combing code in the third so I must be sure that I will process all Statistics received from server, will ignore all errors returned from database(only if i will find Currency finally, if all requests will fail I have to return default value), and will make only one successful request to database, will put this object in result entity and that give it back
Combing function may look like:

```
private fun getCombinedStatistics(): Single<TestDashboardStatistics> {
        return Single.create<TestDashboardStatistics> {
            var transactionsAmount = 0.0
            var cashBackAmount = 0.0
            var count = 0
            var currency = TestCurrency(-1, "default")

            getStatistics().subscribe({ statistic ->
                ++count
                transactionsAmount += statistic.doubleAmount
                cashBackAmount += statistic.doubleCashBack
                getCurrencyById(statistic.currencyId).subscribe({ cur ->
                    // TODO do not request currency for future statistics because we have it now but
                    // TODO because different threads we can subscribe for new request before we will receive this result
                    currency = cur
                }, { err ->
                    // TODO ignore error if there is a hope that other statistics will have valid currency code
                })
            }, {
                // On requesting statistics error just throw it up
                Single.error<TestDashboardStatistics>(it)
            }, {
                // When all statistics will be received and precessed emit result
                // But it could be called even before we will receive any response from database
                Single.just(TestDashboardStatistics(count, cashBackAmount, transactionsAmount, currency))
            })
        }
    }
```

One solution which come to me is to make request for currency from database somehow blocking processing statistics, so processing will wait until db request will be finished, and that go to another, but my knowledge of Rx operators is pretty bad so I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: what does the field ``count`` represent? what's its purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to leave the db request blocking as you suggested:

```
data class TestStatistics(val doubleCashBack: Double, val doubleAmount: Double, val currencyId: Int)
data class TestCurrency(val currencyId: Int, val currencySign: String)
data class TestDashboardStatistics(val count: Int?, val cashBack: Double, val amount: Double, val testCurrency: TestCurrency)

object Helloworld {
    private fun getStatistics(): Observable<TestStatistics> {
        return Observable
            .fromIterable(listOf(
                TestStatistics(1.1, 1.2, 4),
                TestStatistics(2.1, 2.2, 1),
                TestStatistics(3.1, 3.2, 99),
                TestStatistics(4.1, 4.3, 2),
                TestStatistics(5.1, 5.3, 3)
            ))
            .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

    private fun getCurrencyById(id: Int): TestCurrency? {
        // blocking call
        return when (id) {
            1 -> TestCurrency(1, "!")
            2 -> TestCurrency(2, "@")
            3 -> TestCurrency(3, "#")
            else -> null
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        getStatistics()
            .map { getCurrencyById(it.currencyId) to it }
            .filter { it.first != null }
            .map { TestDashboardStatistics(null, it.second.doubleCashBack, it.second.doubleAmount, it.first!!) }
            .subscribe { println(it) }

        Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
}
```

I made the `count` field nullable, as I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve.

I would also recommend you to leave out the `subscribeOn` calls from your helper methods and put them into the `main` method (along with the `observeOn()` function), where you chain your business logic. This way you can switch threads between different operations (e.g. subscribe on the `ui` thread, make db calls on an `io` thread, execute heavy algorithms on the `computation` thread, etc.)

Hope this helps :)

P.S. as far as I understood your use-case, all you need is a simple `map` operation: `TestStatistics` -> `TestDashboardStatistics`. If you don't want to go to the database for `TestCurrency` every time, you could cache already fetched instances (using a `Map`??).

Comment: Thank you, I know that removing subscribeOn from function will resolve my problem because I will be able to manage thread work directly where I would call it, but I thought that there is a way to solve this problem somehow with rx operators, I will try your answere